# How to add two dimensional array , this the program

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need sum of Dimensional arrays..........
   How to add sum of two dimensional array, i done upto this but when i try to add marks[i][j] it is not getting possible for me..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwoDimArray {
    static int i, j;
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int [ ][ ] marks = new int [4][4];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (i = 1; i < marks.length ; i ++) {
            System.out.println ("Enter marks of student "+i);
            for ( j = 1; j < marks[i].length ; j++) {
                System.out.println ("Subject "+j);
                marks [i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        } 
        for ( i = 1; i < marks.length ; i++) {
            for ( j = 1; j < marks[i].length ; j++){
                System.out.print (marks[i][j]+" ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
output:
Enter marks of student 1
Subject 1
45
Subject 2
48
Subject 3
47
Enter marks of student 2
Subject 1
52
Subject 2
56
Subject 3
54
Enter marks of student 3
Subject 1
65
Subject 2 
66
Subject 3
75

45 48 47 52 56 54 65 66 75 
*/
```

i want sum  marks[i][j], how can i add the sum of that 
    subjects ,please explain how to subjects     sum...

Comment: You have an `int sum`, and you add the marks to it.

Comment: To start with, arrays start with index 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple. First some comments:

- `static int i, j;` No idea why you would want to do this. Just declare them within the for-loop.
- since you don't do anything with `i` and `j` other than selecting the right mark, use a foreach loop: `for (int[] marksFromStudent : marks) {...`
- the first array index is 0, not 1.

And now for the code. Ive added some code to also show the student totals:

```
int[][] marks = getMarksFromScanner(); //the question is not about this part; might as well omit it.
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    int studentTotal = 0;
    for (int mark : marks[i]) 
        studentTotal += mark;
    System.out.println("student " + i + " has a total of " + studentTotal + " points");
    total += studentTotal;
}
System.out.println("The whole class scored " + total + " points");
```

or a plain version without the student sum:

```
int[][] marks = getMarksFromScanner(); //the question is not about this part; might as well omit it.
int total = 0;
for (int[] studentMarks : marks)
    for (int mark : studentMarks)
        total += mark;
System.out.println(total);
```